# How to set output of command in variables and then use for further serach in batch scripting

Tags: batch-file

For eg: `Set var=findstr "name" temp.txt [temp.txt consist multiple lines , out of which one line says "my name is ABC"]` later on find the last word of the line i.e. ABC

Comment: ok, question again, would you write the output to file or what do you want to do with it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To capture the output of a command, use a `for /f` loop.  See `help for` for more information.

#### Exercise 1

To set the value of `%var%` to the output of `findstr`, do it something like this:

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /i "name" "temp.txt"') do set "var=%%I"
```

Then if you want the last word of the line, you can use a basic `for` loop to loop through each word of `%var%`.

```
for %%I in (%var%) do set "lastword=%%I"
set "var=%lastword%"
```

---

#### Exercise 2

Alternatively, if you know that the line containing "name" will always be 4 tokens long (as in, "My name is blah"), you can simply capture the fourth token of the output of `findstr` like this.

```
for /f "tokens=4" %%I in ('findstr /i "name" "temp.txt"') do set "var=%%I"
```

And that's it.  `%var%` will contain the fourth word of the line matched by `findstr`.

---

#### Exercise 3

If you know that the line will always begin with "My name is" but you want the possibility of a first and last name, or lots of names like "John Jacob Jingleheimer-Schmidt", you can use `tokens` to capture what you want similar to Exercise 2.

```
for /f "tokens=3*" %%I in ('findstr /i "name" "temp.txt"') do set "var=%%J"
```

Notice that I captured `%%J` instead of `%%I` this time.  That's because `%%I` would be token 3 (the third word), while `%%J` is everything thereafter (the wildcard in `tokens=3*`).

---

#### Exercise 4

Or if it's possible that the name could be a first and last name, but you know it will be preceded by "My name is", you can remove the "My name is" part via [variable substring substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php).

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /i "name" "temp.txt"') do set "var=%%I"
set "var=%var:My name is =%"
```

which will strip "My Name is " from the value of `%var%`, leaving you with "John Smith".

---

#### Exercise 5

If you can't count on the line containing "name" to be the same number of words (for instance, "Hi there!  My name is" or "Hello!  My name is", you can use [variable substring substitution](http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php) with a wildcard to strip out variable content.  This should work regardless of whether the name is one word or more, and regardless of whether the content before "name is" varies.

```
for /f "delims=" %%I in ('findstr /i "name" "temp.txt"') do set "var=%%I"
set "var=%var:*name is =%"
```

Answer (score 0):

Like other programming languages also in batch you can store variables in the memory for further use:

```
@echo off&setlocal

set "file=temp.txt"
set "search=name"

:: clear the local environment
for /f "delims==" %%i in ('set $ 2^>nul') do set "%%i="

:: find the lines containing %search%
for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr "%search%" "%file%"') do set "$%%i=%%i"

:: show the line variables
set $
```

Comment: Interesting.  Not sure how useful it is, as he'd still need another `for` loop to parse the output of `set $` to capture the last token.  This is sort of a Rube Goldberg solution to the OP's problem.  But at least it does offer the ability to store multiple matches.

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem could be. It might be a nonsense machine, but it's a nice one.

Comment: I'll grant you that.  `:>`